# How do I deploy a next.js app with a custom backend (express) to a VPS or Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, vps

How do I deploy a next.js app with a custom backend (specifically express) to a VPS or Heroku.

Comment: Afaik, heroku will run `npm run start` by default, so you need to a) make sure that runs your express app and b) push your git repo to heroku.

Comment: Sorry, but I have one folder named app and the app folder contains server files and a client folder, the client folder contains the next.js front-end app. How can I setup the server so that on getting ```*``` it shows the next.js app, I mean like we would do in create react app

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm also trying to deploy my Next.js project on a customized VPS

Answer (score 2):

I have the same setup.

- server.js (express)
- client (react app)

I used this and it works:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

Comment: The setup is for react?

Comment: Yes, I thought the same works for next.js but I tried it and it doesn't work. I will now try to use the custom server template and try it with that. Did you find another solution in the meantime?

Comment: @daninad did you find a way? I'm trying to create a customized VPS with Hostinger to deploy my Next.js. Can't find info on it tho.

Comment: @G6ix It's been a long time, but this worked for me:   

`"scripts": {
    
    "build": "next build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",`

Comment: I used Heroku for that

Comment: @daninad do you know if I use "build": "next build" for a dinamic project (using graphcms and node)it'll work just find or I need to use something else? I see a lot of tutorials using next build for projects that are more static than dynamic. Cheers!